# How to find current user group from Active Directory

Tags: c#, active-directory

How to find current user group from Active Directory Server

refer screenshot url.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1dww.png

For the username "palani", Group is **Administrators**.

How it can be get from Active Directory server

Answer (score 0):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    // find currently logged in user
    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "palani");

    if(user != null)
    {
         foreach(GroupPrincipal group in user.GetAuthorizationGroups().OfType<GroupPrincipal>())
         {
            Console.WriteLine("Group name: {0}", group.Name);
         }
    }
}
```

A user can be member of any number of groups - there isn't *the group* for a given user - there just is the list of groups he/she is a member of.

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!

Comment: I am getting following error,
{System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalOperationException: While trying to retrieve the authorization groups, an error (5) occurred. at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.AuthZSet..ctor(Byte[] userSid, NetCred credentials, ContextOptions contextOptions, String flatUserAuthority, StoreCtx userStoreCtx, Object userCtxBase)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.GetGroupsMemberOfAZ(Principal p)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroups()
   at LDAP.LdapAuthentication.GetGroups()}

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domain.com",
                                  "CN=palani,OU=Department,DC=domain,DC=com",
                                                             "administrator",
                                                                 "password");
        UserPrincipal usr = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx,"palani");
        if(usr!=null){
            Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(usr.SamAccountName));
            PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> group = usr.GetGroups();
            foreach(Principal pr in group)
                Console.WriteLine(pr.Name);
        }
        Console.Read();
```